# cf ORM - access generated property immediately after entitySave() on new entity

Tags: hibernate, coldfusion

I am creating a new Entity, saving it with entitySave(), then want to get the ID for that entity before the page request finishes.

When I run the getter on the ID, it returns '0', but when I check, the database has generated the ID.

Here is my property declaration in my model:

```
property name="id" fieldtype="id" generator="identity" column="member_id";
```

I create and save the entity, then try to access the new Entities ID:

```
newProfile = entityNew("member");
newProfile.setMemento(args); // a helper method to populate the entity
entitySave(newProfile);

//ormFlush() // have tried this, but makes no difference
//ormReload(newProfile) //  have tried this, but no difference

//I now want to access the ID of the new profile, but it is returning '0'
newProfileID = newProfile.getID();
```

Have also tried this without success

```
transaction {
        entitySave(newProfile);
    }

    writeDump(newProfile);
```

Any pointers on what I might be missing here?

Many Thanks!

**UPDATE****
It looks like an issue with the colomn mapping.  If I change the property name to be anything other than "id", it works fine.  It is only if the property name is "id" that the property doesn't pick up the generated value:

This configuration has getID() with a value of 0:

```
property name="id" fieldtype="id" generator="identity" column="member_id";
```

Changing property name to something other than 'id' returns the value of member_id in the DB.

```
property name="myid" fieldtype="id" generator="identity" column="member_id";
```

Comment: Property name "id" works for me when I use your code in a simple test app using MySQL. What DB are you using? Can you post your application.cfc ormsettings and also more of your "member" component definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only resolution I was able to find to this one is...

It looks like an issue with the column mapping. If I **change the property name to be anything other than "id"**, it works fine. It is only if the property name is "id" that the property doesn't pick up the generated value:

This configuration has getID() with a value of 0:

```
property name="id" fieldtype="id" generator="identity" column="member_id";
```

Changing property name to something other than 'id' returns the value of member_id in the DB:

```
property name="myid" fieldtype="id" generator="identity" column="member_id";
```

Comment: FWIW, if you do need/want a getId method, you can add a simple alias function to the object, i.e: `function getId() {return getMemberId();}` (where MemberId would be the property name).

Answer (score 1):

You need to force Hibernate to run the query right away, because, by default, the queries get run at the end of the request.

You can try:

```
transaction{
    entitySave(newProfile);
}
```

Or

```
entitySave(newProfile);
ORMFlush();
```

Either of those will cause Hibernate to run the query when you want it to.

Comment: Thanks Scott.  That is what i thought, but neither of those (wrapping in transaction, or ORMFlush post save) are working.  See edited question.  Thanks!